# Mongoose cached connection in NextJS 14

Tags: mongoose, next.js

I need help understanding WHY we need to cache a mongoose connection when using NextJS 14 with API routes or server actions.

I'm using the following code and it's working perfectly:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI!;

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local",
  );
}


// Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
// in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
// during API Route usage.
let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }
  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };
    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose;
    });
  }
  try {
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  } catch (e) {
    cached.promise = null;
    throw e;
  }

  return cached.conn;
}

export default dbConnect;
```

The comment in the code above mentions that the cached connection is used for hot reloads only during development. But from what I understand, every time an API route or server action is run, a new db connection is opened and afterwards the connection is terminated. So how exactly is a connection being cached. Kindly explain this in detail. And also, will this defensive caching approach have any downside when used in production?